# git installation failing, windows 10, CryptStringToBinaryW

Tags: git, floating-point, windows-10, cpu, motherboard

Git for windows is failing to install, I've redownloaded numerous times.

The install log looks like this :

```
2021-05-07 09:02:33.191   -- DLL function import --
2021-05-07 09:02:33.191   Function name: CryptStringToBinaryW
2021-05-07 09:02:33.191   DLL name: crypt32.dll
2021-05-07 09:02:33.191   Dest DLL name: crypt32.dll
2021-05-07 09:02:33.191   Importing the DLL function.
2021-05-07 09:02:33.191   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2021-05-07 09:02:33.221   Exception message:
2021-05-07 09:02:33.221   Message box (OK):
                          Invalid floating point operation.
2021-05-07 09:05:07.456   User chose OK.
2021-05-07 09:05:07.456   Deinitializing Setup.
2021-05-07 09:05:07.458   Log closed.
```

Each install, the last action is CryptStringToBinaryW import followed by floating point overflow error ... I think I may have a hardware issue ?

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking here? Are you looking for someone who has had the same problem who didn’t post the solution to or the underlying reason for the problem on the internet, but somehow stumbles across this question..?

Comment: @stuartd is it really that confusing what I'm asking? To clarify I'm asking how to fix a failing git installation and I provided the error log.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [obvious issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/search?q=CryptStringToBinaryW) reported in [`git-for-windows/git`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git), so you might have to report one with your exact setup (Windows version, and possible additional firewall/antivirus setup)

Just for testing, double-check:

- you have the 64-bit version of the installer
- try and unzip [`PortableGit-2.31.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.31.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.31.1-64-bit.7z.exe), to see if the portable version works.

Comment: this ended up being a dodgy cpu, anything that used the crypt dll didn't work

Answer (score 0):

replaced the cpu and everything worked. There were other problems associated with that crypt lib, alongside the failing git install.

Comment: Might as well delete the question, then.  Or maybe `CryptStringToBinaryW` makes a CPU draw more power than most other functions or is otherwise more sensitive to the kinds of errors that failing voltage regulators could cause.  That's the only reason to consider keeping it around, otherwise it's just a random failure that could have happened in any function in any software package.